# How do I animate restoration of an element after using the size effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I'm using the size effect to decrease my element's height from 100 to 80px. Later I want to animate the element back to its original state, however, using the size effect again results in many slight off css styles (which is expected).

How do I animate the restoration of this element's correctly?

In other words, if I do:

```
$("my_element").effect("size", { to: { height: "80px" } });
```

how do I *animate* `$("my_element")` back to exactly it's pre-resize state?

The methods I'm coming up with are messy and very dependent on the internal implementation of the size effect.

**EDIT:**

doing this is not good enough:

```
$("my_element").effect("size", { to: { height: "100px" } });
```

as it leaves many other styles tacked on to the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store a .clone()'d copy of the element, then when your effect's complete event is fired, replace the element on the DOM with the copy you made prior to any effects.

Comment: To clarify a bit - I was thinking that you could use the size effect again, setting it back to the original size value (at that point, leaving you with a slightly off css style, as you mentioned).  It is at that point that you could replace the currently-off DOM element with your copy.  The difference between them at that point should be so slight as to not warrant a transition effect.

Comment: let me try it, I thought it would look strange. Maybe not.

Comment: I'm doing this to replace the element ``el.before(clone).remove();`` however I'm losing the original bindings on ``el``. Is there a more appropriate way to do this? I def need these bindings.

Answer (score 1):

The data- element is your friend here. Just set the initial value like so:

```
$('#my_element').data('height', $('#my_element').height()).effect("size", { to: { height: "80px" } });
```

Then when you need to go back:

```
$('#my_element').effect("size", { to: { height: $('#my_element').data('height') +"px" } });
```

(Edited based on your comment)
Since you're changing a lot of properties, I'll suggest this route. I don't know if it's the best solution, but it will work.

Create a global object for storing the state of the elements you want to animate.

```
var elementState = {};
```

for each element you will animate, store it's initial state. You can create a sort of associative array (just named properties of the object) using the IDs of your elements.

```
elementState['my_element'] = $('#my_element')[0].style;
```

This will store the `style` attribute of object.
To get at this information when you want to go back, you can do:

```
//put the height back to normal
$('#my_element').effect("size", { to: { height: elementState['my_element'].height + "px" } });
```

Comment: From what it looks like you're just caching the original height in jquery's datastore. I know the final target height, the problem is more that the resize effect overrides many other styles than just height.